# Redirecting the site collection

Tags: 2013, 2016

I have a site collection with URL `https://MySharepoint.Dev.com/default.aspx`.

I just want to know if some one browses to this it should redirect to `https://MySharepoint.Dev.com` without `default.aspx` page.

I have almost around 30 sitecollections like this. Is there any setting where we can just include like that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would use URL Rewrite module for this with pattern

```
(?:[^*]+)(?=\/default\.aspx)
```

In case you wish to get rid of /pages/ as well, use this for pattern

```
(?:[^*]+)(?=\/pages\/default\.aspx)
```

and Rewrite URL

```
{R:0}
```

It will tackle at least these scenarios

- http://mysp.com/sites/somesite/default.aspx
- https://mysp.com/default.aspx
- https://www.mysp.com/default.aspx?qsvalue=asdad
- https://www.mysp.com/sites/asdasd/default.aspx?qsvalue=asdad

[image]

Details on configuring URL Rewrite module can be found [here](https://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/testing-rewrite-rule-patterns).

Comment: I tried this but still when i browse ( http://mysp.com/Pages/default.aspx). it still browse the same default.aspx page

Comment: If you test that URL in "Test pattern..." dialog, does it match your Pattern and return correct redirect URL in the {R:0} variable?

Comment: Yes It is Returning up to Pages. But when i browse the url it is not

Comment: Oh, your question didn't have /Pages/ there in the middle. If in browser you type just http://mysp.com, to what page you end up?

Comment: I tried for the site which has http://mysite.sarepoint.com/default.aspx. It works in the Rewrite Condition but it does not work when i paste the same url in browser